# Error on accessing email even with administrator login in odoo 14

Tags: odoo-14

I am using odoo 14 community edition.
I am facing error when click on email (Setting/Technical/Email)
In start its working fine but now its giving following error;

The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: Message, Operation: read) - (Records: [512], User: 2)

Comment: by using option Become Superuser, i can open and read email. Any way to give rights OdooBot to administrator.